# How do I get the row as column and one of the column as rows under the first column data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have table like below:

```
Tname         Scode
-----         -----
SVC           code1
SVC           code2
SVC           code3
AKV           code1
AKV           code12
AKV           code3
AKS           code3
AKS           code2
AKS           code1
```

I would want a result like below:

```
SVC      AKV         AKS
----     -----       ----
code1    code1       code3
code2    code12      code2
code3    code3       code1
```

Comment: What determines which columns end up in which row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I think it's usefull, and will fix the problem if you have more codes in a column, I'm just trying to not select the `row_number` column.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Tname,scode,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tname ORDER BY Scode) 
     FROM teste_1) AS src
PIVOT (
  MIN(scode)
  FOR Tname IN ([SVC],[AKV],[AKS])
) AS pvt


| rn | SVC   | AKV    | AKS   | 
|----|-------|--------|-------|
| 1  | bola  | code1  | code1 |   
| 2  | code1 | code12 | code2 |   
| 3  | code2 | code3  | code3 |   
| 4  | code3 | NULL   | NULL  |
```

Comment: Please, do not use images, use some online table generator like this: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# (copy and paste)

Comment: @McNets - I'm curious as to why you think we should use this markdown stuff in lieu images for representing result set answers like this.  We wouldn't really be trying to select the results as text.  I'm interested in what you perceive as the benefits of the markdown stuff - I'm willing to learn new stuff, but I want to know why one way is better than another way.

Comment: @ScottHodgin for the same reason that one OP shouldn't use its on a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3270427). Text (tables) will be there for ever.

Comment: @mcnets - valid points

Comment: Oh Sure, I didn't know about this `tabeGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks all, i will try this but the Tname in the table I specified are not static, there are many entries. So I need a query which will display distinct Tnames in columns.

Comment: I THINK you should try "dynamic Pivot". I used it one time in the past, but as i'm not a programmer I really don't remember what I did. But it was for a situation like this.

Comment: I did some research on dynamic pivot without aggregate but didnt get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Inner Join` to display the three queries horizontally. Then use `Row_number` for setting join conditions,

As a **demo**:-

```
create table #temp (Tname varchar(10) , Scode varchar(10))
insert into #temp values ('SVC','code1')
insert into #temp values ('SVC','code2')
insert into #temp values ('SVC','code3')
insert into #temp values ('AKV','code1')
insert into #temp values ('AKV','code12')
insert into #temp values ('AKV','code3')
insert into #temp values ('AKS','code3')
insert into #temp values ('AKS','code2')
insert into #temp values ('AKS','code1')

go 

SELECT SVC , AKV , AKS
FROM (
    select Scode as SVC , row_number() over(partition by Tname order by (select 1)) rn  
    from #temp where Tname = 'SVC')  t1
INNER JOIN (
    select  Scode as AKV , row_number() over(partition by Tname order by (select 1)) rn 
    from #temp where Tname = 'AKV' )  t2
    on t1.rn = t2.rn
INNER JOIN (
    select  Scode as AKS , row_number() over(partition by Tname order by (select 1)) rn 
    from #temp where Tname = 'AKS' ) t3
    on t2.rn = t3.rn


--drop table #temp
```

**Result**:-

```
| SVC       | AKV       | AKS       |
|-------    |--------   |-------    |
| code2     | code1     | code3     |
| code3     | code12    | code2     |
| code3     | code3     | code1     |
```

Comment: But, Let's say I have more Scodes in one of these columns. how can I show it, even if it shows 'null' in the other columns? I'm trying to code it but i can't think in something useful.

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli You are right, but I think this is not the case for OP.

Comment: Oh Yes I know, I was just curious to use your code when Needed haha.